# SP is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, nintex-workflow, sharepoint-jsom

I am trying to use JavaScript inside a Nintex Form for Office 365. When I write the code inside the `Custom JavaCript` block of the form settings, it works perfect. However when I use my own JavaScript file and put it into the `Advanced` block it doesn't work and says `SP is not defined`. When I look the developer tools I see that my JavaScript file is loaded before sp.js and JQuery.

Is there a way to make my JavaScript be loaded last? or solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add sp.js and JQuery libraries in Settings - Form > Advanced > Custom Javascript Includes.

See this post for more help:

http://www.vadimtabakman.com/nintex-forms-using-javascript-libraries.aspx